# How to get the inverse of the propagator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, greens-functions, propagator

> For a free EM Lagrangian, the propagator is as below in momentum space:
>   $$
> S[A]=\int d^4kA_{\mu}(k)\underbrace{[-k^2g^{\mu\nu}+k^{\mu}k^{\nu}]}_{M}A_{\nu}(k).
> $$
>   It is easy to calculate the $\det(M)$ which is equal zero. This is the reason we fix the gauge via i.e Lorenz gauge $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}=0$. If one implements this into Lagrangian
>   $$
> L=-\frac{1}{4}(F_{\mu\nu})^2-\frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu})^2.
> $$
>   Then one obtains the Green's equation as follows
>   $$
> \underbrace{(-k^2g_{\mu\nu}+(1-\frac{1}{\xi})k_{\mu}k_{\nu})}_MG_F^{\nu\rho}(k)=i\delta^{\rho}_{\mu}.
> $$
>   Then taking the inverse of $M$ one should get the photon propagator as below
>   $$
> G_F^{\mu\nu}(k)=\frac{-i}{k^2}(g^{\mu\nu}-(1-\xi)\frac{k^{\mu}k^{\nu}}{k^2}).
> $$

I do not see how am I suppose to obtain the propagator. Can anyone show me the way to get the final result?

Comment: @qftishard this method seems to me that an informal "educated guess" :) which solves the puzzle indeed. I can not object but also, taking the inverse of the Green's function may have an analytic solution which I do not know the way of obtaining it.